# Nontrivial examples of compact topological fields

Tags: general-topology, field-theory

Are there any nontrivial examples of compact topological fields? Meaning fields with a topological structure so that addition and multiplication are continuous.

With non-trivial I mean non-finite fields (finite fields will be compact in any topology) that are preferably Hausdorff or something else to prevent simply taking the trivial topology.

An example of a compact field would be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ with the topology where the closed sets are a finite amount of points. This space is $T_0$ but it is not Hausdorff.

Comment: Every (Hausdorff ) compact field is finite, mentioned in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48718/is-every-compact-topological-ring-a-profinite-ring.

Comment: The cofinite topology is not even a group topology, because for those $T_1$ implies $T_2$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma The difference is from demanding that multiplication/addition is continuous on $K\times K$ or that for each $a\in K$ addition/multiplication with $a$ is continuous on $K$. In what I said I took the second definition, with which $T_0$ does not imply $T_2$. But I guess it is the wrong definition, since you should want a topological field to also be a topological group.